# How to update a certain value in a table once a certain custom time has been met CRON JOB - PHP

Tags: php, cron

I'm having trouble updating a certain value in a table once a custom time has been met using a CRON JOB and PHP

### DB EXAMPLE

USERS TABLE

| id | uid | active | custom_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 0 | 2021/02/03 21:29:25 |

I want to make a **CRON JOB** that uses this **custom_time** and update the active value to **1** once the date and time is the same as the **custom_time**

I've had trouble finding resources online for using custom_times in a CRON JOB.
I didn't want to run a CRON JOB every 30 min because it seems a little cumbersome.

Any help would be widely appreciated

Thanks,
Arnav

Comment: Why does running the cron job every half an hour seem cumbersome? How long would this job last?

Answer (score 0):

It could be actualy worse to set cron jobs to specific times using `custom_time` if your users table contain a lot of results marked with `active = 0`.
I recommend running simple update script every 30 minutes or less based on your needs.
Its not "cumbersome" in any way.
You just need to use sql update query like below to update records which are "in past"
`UPDATE users SET active = 1 WHERE active = 0 AND custom_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`
P.s.: This sql statement is written for mysql. Refer to your DB documentation for more info on working with dates if you are using another DB